# Group results by same column value

Tags: php, sql, yii2

Im trying the following:

I have a model (HbwerllMargins) with the following fields:

```
id| userId | clinicId | payMethodId | percentage | createdTime | updatedTime | deletedTime
```

Im trying the following query:

```
$hbwellMargins = HbwellMargins::find()->andWhere(['clinicId' => $id])->all();
```

Where result is associated to a certain clinicId value, but what I need is also to group the result by the same userId values without specifying a value.

For example, for clinicId=1, userId = 1 has 6 registers, userId = 2, has 1 register, etc

Im trying to find out in ActiveQuery Documentation but I havent found yet a solution...what I would need to do that? Is there any way to do that?

Thans a lot for your help!!

Comment: Do you need the `andWhere(['clinicId' => $id])` clause in your query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group the result by the same `userId` values like this:

If you just want to fetch all records and group the results:

```
$hbwellMargins = HbwellMargins::find()->orderBy('userId')->all();
```

If you want to fetch results with your condition and group the results:

```
$hbwellMargins = HbwellMargins::find()->where(['clinicId' => $id])->orderBy('userId')->all();
```

Comment: I tried, but it only takes first value associated to userId=1, in my example, and I need a way to group six registers associated to userId=1, and so on...you know any smart solution? thanks a lot for your contribution

Comment: @BerTsacianegudelTepuy, I have updated my answer. check it out.